# Bad Experiences with Online Poker Sites

Tags: online, poker-tools

I am doing a survey of online poker sites, and I want to know if anyone has any particularly bad experiences with any of them, refusing refunds, continual crashes, or anything else.

Comment: Yes I have and I am out 15-20K with no recourse. They are slime, I will never play online again.

Comment: Care to elaborate @Jon?

Comment: No, beyond saying that when the port Authority act passed a number of sites just disappeared, and resurfaced with new owners and new affiliate programs. Costing me a lot of money.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I had to close this. Like you said: it's more of a survey, a poll, which is very out-of-touch with StackExchange's Q&A model. In this form, there's no way to determine what the correct answer is.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my gripes on the few sites I've played - YMMV:

**PokerStars**

Poor currency conversion rate. Also owns Full Tilt but that has a *better* conversion rate - go figure.

Dreadful rakeback

**888**

Poor interface, crashy software, cashier problems, very slow support.

**Full Tilt**

Laggy at times

**PKR**

Charge for cashouts below a certain limit

Answer (score 0):

Bovada: happily takes your deposit but when you cash out they want an imprint of your card, drivers license, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Full Tilt - gets shut down by FBI from one day to another and all money gets locked for a year.